# Show each point of A is isolated

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

[image]

I can follow the argument, I'm unsure as to how they came up with that epsilon value. Could anyone clear that up for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}$. The numbers of the form $\frac1k$ which are closest to (but distinct from) $\frac1n$ are $\frac1{n-1}$ and $\frac1{n+1}$. But $\frac1{n+1}$ is actually the closest one. Therefore, the open interval$$\left(\frac1n-\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right),\frac1n+\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)\right)$$is the largest interval centered at $\frac1n$ which has no element of the form $\frac1k$ other than $\frac1n$.

Comment: Thanks! So we're looking for the smallest epsilon neighbourhood possible around 1/n and we choose 1/n+1 because it's smaller than the alternative?

Then since the intersection of our epsilon neighbourhood and our set is just the set {1/n} and doesn't contain any other points meaning that it is not a limit point and consequently an isolated point?

Comment: Is the reason that we choose the epsilon neighbourhood to be so small is that we don't want the intersection to inclue anything other than 1/n?

Comment: No, we are **not**  looking for the smallest $\varepsilon$ neighbourhood possible around $\frac1n$. There is no such thing, since if an $\varepsilon$ neighbourhood works, any smaller one will work too. Actually, the neighbourhood that I described is the *largest* $\varepsilon$ neighbourhood around $\frac1n$ that works.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. So how would I know which ε neighbourhood would be appropriate? I understand it would be of a similar form to elements of set A.

Comment: Any $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\left(\frac1n-\varepsilon,\frac1n+\varepsilon\right)\cap A=\left\{\frac1n\right\}$ will do. In this specific case, a good choice is to take$$\varepsilon=\min\left\{\left\lvert\frac1n-\frac1k\right\rvert\,\middle|\,k\in\mathbb N\setminus\{n\}\right\}=\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}.$$